# Phpmailer not able to send mail

Tags: php, phpmailer

i am  trying to send mail using phpmailer . 
The mail->Send is  returning true but the  mail  is not  delivered

```
<?php
try {
    require_once('include/class.phpmailer.php');
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
    $mail->MailerDebug = true;
    $mail->IsSendmail();
    $mail->From = "library@capitalvia.com";
    $mail->FromName = "Library | CapitalVia";
    $mail->AddAddress("kanhaiya.lal@capitalvia.com", "Kanhaiyalal");
    $mail->AddReplyTo("library@capitalvia.com", "Library | CapitalVia");
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = "Here is the subject";
    $mail->Body = "This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>";
    $mail->AltBody = "This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients";
    if ($mail->Send())
        echo "Message has been sent";
} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
    echo $e->errorMessage();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Comment: There is no such property as `MailerDebug`, so setting it will do nothing. You're using `isSendMail()` - do you have that configured? Any particular reason not to use the default `isMail()` way? Either way, your mail server will have more info in its logs.

Answer (score -1):

My first guess would be that you forgot to configure the smtp server. If no smtp server is provided the PHPMailer class won't be able to send the e-mail.
Try adding something like this:

```
$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->Host       = "mail.yourdomain.com"; // SMTP server
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
                                           // 1 = errors and messages
                                           // 2 = messages only
// OR this if authentication is needed
$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Host       = "mail.yourdomain.com"; // sets the SMTP server
$mail->Port       = 26;                    // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
$mail->Username   = "yourname@yourdomain"; // SMTP account username
$mail->Password   = "yourpassword";        // SMTP account password
```

This information can be found in the configuration/properties of your e-mail account in your e-mailing application (Outlook, Mail, Thunderbird, ...).

[This](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/?pg=examplebgmail) is an example for Gmail.

Comment: actually i am sending the  mail to internal domain ,is  it  necessary to configure the smtp if all the mails  will  go internally

Comment: Yes it is. PHPMailer does not know if you're sending the mail internally or not. It also doesn't look at the configuration of the server to know which mail server to use. This is a tutorial from PHPMailer describing on how to do this: [link](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=tutorial)

Comment: No it's not. PHPMailer will quite happily use a local mail server without SMTP, in fact this is what it does by default. That tutorial is also years out of date.